# What's the issue with the "\" character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, backslash

What's the problem with "\" character in JavaScript?

This script doesn't work:

```
var theText='<he:/ll/*o?|>'
function clean(txt) {
var chr = [ '\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '<', '>', '|' ];
for(i=0;i<=8;i++){txt=txt.split(chr[i]).join("")}
return txt;}
alert(clean(theText));
```

It works when I remove the "backslash" from the array:

```
var theText='<he:/ll/*o?|>'
function clean(txt) {
var chr = [ '/', ':', '*', '?', '<', '>', '|' ];
for(i=0;i<=7;i++){txt=txt.split(chr[i]).join("")}
return txt;}
alert(clean(theText));
```

It doesn't work when I write `var txt='text\';`

The mistake may arise from the quotes joined with backslash, like this: `\'` or `'\'`

But I need the / character too, what can I do?

Comment: You need to stop using Notepad and switch to some IDE, like SublimeText 2 or Notepad++ at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backslash escapes the closing quote. You need to escape the backslash itself:

```
var chr = [ '\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '<', '>', '|' ];
//           ^--- Add another backslash to escape the original one
```

This behaviour could come in useful if, for example, you wanted to add a single quote character to your array:

```
var chr = [ ''', '/', ':', '*', '?', '<', '>', '|' ];
//           ^--- This quote closes the first and the 3rd will cause an error
```

By escaping the single quote, it gets treated as a 'normal' character and won't close the string:

```
var chr = [ '\'', '/', ':', '*', '?', '<', '>', '|' ];
//           ^--- Escaped quote, no problem
```

You should be able to see the difference between the previous two examples from the syntax highlighting applied by Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks, it works now, i just need to add another backslash, but are it's still works to replace one backslash?

Comment: @faid - I'm not sure what you mean... do you have an example?

Comment: ex. my char is this `'<he:/l\l/*o\?|>'` and i want to replace with JS function above with adding another backslah like:`'\\'`, are it's still work, i've test in IE8 and it's works well, but whether it will be fine in other usage?

Comment: @faid - Yes, it will always work. Any time you want to use a literal `\` character in a string you will have to escape it by adding another backslash before it.